# Spring MVC @Value/@ConfigurationProperties working on MainConfig but not on SecurityConfig

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, properties, autowired

I have a simple Spring MVC 5 project, with security layer enabled. Everything works good except the properties loading, only on Security Config.
I let you the scenario so you can see it.

application.properties (located at src/main/resources)

```
com.company.myapp.prop=myprop
```

MainConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class MainConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Value("${com.company.myapp.prop}")
    private String prop;

    @Bean
    public MySpecialBean mySpecialBean() {
        System.out.println(prop); // output > myprop
        return new MySpecialBean();
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${com.company.myapp.prop}")
    private String prop;

    @Bean
    public MySpecialSecurityBean mySpecialSecurityBean() {
        System.out.println(prop); // output > null
        return new MySpecialSecurityBean();
    }
}
```

I don't understand why it's happening. I already switched the @EnableWebSecurity annotation to the app class, try to set the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer myself, but nothing works.
Do you have any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

From official docs about @PropertySource:

**Resolving ${...} placeholders in <bean> and @Value annotations**

> In order to resolve ${...} placeholders in  definitions or @Value annotations using properties from a PropertySource, you must ensure that an appropriate embedded value resolver is registered in the BeanFactory used by the ApplicationContext. This happens automatically when using  in XML. When using @Configuration classes this can be achieved by explicitly registering a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer via a static @Bean method. Note, however, that explicit registration of a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer via a static @Bean method is typically only required if you need to customize configuration such as the placeholder syntax, etc. See the "Working with externalized values" section of @Configuration's javadocs and "a note on BeanFactoryPostProcessor-returning @Bean methods" of @Bean's javadocs for details and examples.

You should try to add annotation **@PropertySource** into the your config class.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:my.properties")
public class MainConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {}
```

and then try to access your property in **SecurityConfig** class

To get full information see [official docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html)

I hope it will help you

Comment: The problem with @PropertySource annotation is that I have multiple profiles and the annotation have one hardcoded

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.
I guess you have another class that triggers the application and that is annotated with @SpringBootApplication
Also, your methods mySpecialBean do not return a MySpecialBean instance, so this probably does not even compile.
Is there any other class that you are using? Please advice

Comment: This was just an example. I've updated my question. Yes, the app starts at MyWebApplication that is annotated by @SpringBootApplication

Comment: Can you share you pom.xml? Maybe you are using devtools, if you do please remove and test.

Comment: I'm not using devtools.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it!
The problem was related with some dependency priorities and unnecessary beans declarations. Getting into details, I'm working with OAuht2 and I started with [this tutorial](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-security-oauth2-social-login-part-2/). In the end I've made a mix with [this one](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-5-oauth2-login) too (more recent). The problem was related with these @Bean's that don't really need to be declared as beans:

- ClientRegistrationRepository
- ClientRegistration
- OAuth2AuthorizedClientService

Spring was calling these beans before any other configuration, so any properties was not loaded yet. Maybe changing the priority, dependence or even the order would resolve the issue, but as I was analysing the code I found that these methods are only used on security configuration and not really needed along any other part of the app. So I removed the @Bean declaration and all works nice now! At the time these methods are called inside security config the properties are already loaded.

Hope to help someone out there.